# How do I add a zoom hover effect to my thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im currently using Wordpress to build a portfolio site. I need to create a hover effect that is triggered when a mouse enters either. I'm trying to get a box to display over the image area that contains a permalink saying to "view project" about the specific post whilst the thumbnail slowly zooms in. My site is currently responsive as well so I can't use any fixed widths or heights for this.

This is what im aiming for:

[image]

Im basically trying to replicate what Fi are doing with there image hovers here http://blog.f-i.com/

I've posted my current markup on http://jsfiddle.net/estx4/

Thanks

Comment: your markup has no css

Comment: Don't post `PHP` in jSfiddle. Post the resulting `HTML` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go...this is pure css based.

http://jsfiddle.net/2pBG6/

```
.loop-item {
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/qw9DF/).

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $(this).find(".perma").hide(); //to hide the permalink on load
    $(".post-wrap li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".perma").fadeIn("slow"); //show link
        $(this).find(".img").addClass("blur"); //make the image look out of focus
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".perma").fadeOut("slow"); //hide link
        $(this).find(".img").removeClass("blur"); //display image in normal state
    });
});
```